# SSIS - Extract data from a stored proc with no headers

Tags: ssis

I am working on a requirement where I need to execute a stored proc (there are 399 others too) which necessarily dont have a header. Once the stored proc executes, it pulls in varied amounts of rows depending on the table. The problem is, SSIS OLEDB source would not accept a stored proc call which has no header information about the data it is trying to pull. Is there a way to pull the data into a flat file without including the header information?

Thanks for your time.

RV.

Comment: Is the procedure on SQL Server and if so, what version of SQL Server are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wait to hear back, this was my reproduction. I defined a trivial procedure that returns a row of data with no column names defined

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SO_67221181
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 0, 'A', DATEFROMPARTS(2021,4,22);
END
GO
```

Executing the procedure confirms, 3 columns in SSMS with (No column name) and

```
-- No column names
EXECUTE dbo.SO_67221181;
```

When I try to use this in an OLEDB Source, SSIS fails with "There is a data source column with no name. Each data source column must have a name." Clicking around, I can't force a fake column name in there through the standard editor.

[WITH RESULT SETS](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to the rescue!
Starting with SQL Server 2012, we can handle this situation in the invocation of the procedure by using the WITH RESULTS SET clause to EXECUTE.

I explicitly define the shape of my data and now the SSIS OLEDB Source is happy.

```
-- Define the shape
EXECUTE dbo.SO_67221181
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
        Col1 int NOT NULL
    ,   ColA char(1) NOT NULL
    ,   YeDate date NOT NULL
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi Bill. Sorry for the late reply. I was able to get around the issue by using bcp.exe. But when I get a chance to evaluate this in real time, I will keep this handy. Thanks again for taking the time to answer!